# MATLAB - Directly convert nominal data to numeric

Tags: matlab, svm, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, nominal-data

Is there any Matlab function to **directly** convert nominal data to numeric one ?

N.b that currently, and after several searches, I use `NumericGroup=str2num(char(NominalGroup))`

Thanks,

Comment: @PawełKordowski: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: If not for you, please tell us why?

Comment: @amadeus: In fact, it's not what I want. `containers.Map` doesn't convert **directly**, in addition, it requires a second argument which is assumed unknown, rather that's what we seek to determine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double(NominalGroup)` will convert a nominal/categorical array to a double array.

Answer (score 1):

Using the double function is dangerous because it returns the category index of the NominalValue.

Example:

```
color = categorical({'8','9','0'})
x = color(1)  % x = 8
z = double(x) % z = 2
```

I have been loking for a function that gives me z = 8.